# how to draw a rectangle on the image present on QLabel in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am actually designing an app using the pyqt5. in the app in one of the screen i am displaying an image on the QLabel. i want to draw a rectangle on the image. so i used mouse press and release event to  get the mouse press and release values on the image.  i am using the QPainter.drawRect( x, y, widht, height) to draw the rectangle. But the thing is i am getting the correct mouse press and release values when i printed them , but the rectagle is getting drawn with respect to main window.

my windows heirarchy is as follows:
QMainWindow -> QWidget -> QWidget ->  QLabel ->image

i used mapToGlobal, mapFromRect, mapFromGobal , i get correct press and release values globally(with respect to QMainWindow) as well as with respect to QLabel. but i pass those values to draw the rectangle it is drawing somewhere else.

below is the part of the code

```py
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self.demo_room_image)
        pen = QtGui.QPen(Qt.red)
        pen.setWidth(20)    
        painter.setPen(pen)
        painter.drawRect(self.a , self.b , self.c - self.a, self.d - self.b)            
        painter.end()
    
        self.image = QPixmap(self.demo_room_image).scaled(self.picBox.width() - 15,
                                                     self.picBox.height() - 15,
                                                     aspectRatioMode=QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
                                                     transformMode=QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        self.picBox_2.setPixmap(self.image)  
 #picBox_2 is my QLabel


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # Get the mouse press position on the image relative to the main window
            global_pos = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()) 
            self.a = global_pos.x()
            self.b = global_pos.y()
            image_pos = self.mapFromGlobal(global_pos)  
            self.x1 = image_pos.x()
            self.y1 = image_pos.y()

            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            # Get the mouse release position on the image relative to the main window
            global_pos = self.mapToGlobal(event.pos())
            self.c = global_pos.x()# Convert to global coordinates
            self.d =  global_pos.y()  
            image_pos = self.mapFromGlobal(global_pos)  
            self.x2 = image_pos.x()
            self.y2 = image_pos.y()
            self.update()
```

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre].

Answer (score 0):

update : i got it. i was required to use the mapTo function from QLabel to Global event position(even.pos()).and while drawing the retangle i was needed to subtract the offset(x,y) between the QMainwindow and the QLabel